# htaccess redirect localhost exemption

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

At some point through my error my localhost started getting redirected. After reading around I added `RewriteCond !localhost [NC]` to my .htaccess file and it now appears to work but I've pretty much no idea what I'm doing.

I don't know htaccess rules well, I've read several answers and googled but the scripts I've found seem to take a different approach usually based around...

```
Require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

...which I have trouble integrating.

Is my amend below OK or a bad idea?

```
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.00\.000\.000 # my remote IP address
RewriteCond !localhost [NC] # I added this line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|zip) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to remove these lines

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.00\.000\.000 # my remote IP address
RewriteCond !localhost [NC] # I added this line
```

and add just this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(?:(?:00\.00\.000\.000)|(?:127\.0\.0\.1))$
```

But the

```
Require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

Solution is much better.

Comment: OK, that explains why I see the valid-user approach so often then. I used a guide some time ago but I'll try to replace it with your recommendation if I can. Thanks for taking the time to help.